# Casting and exception filters inside an F# `try`-`with` block

Tags: c#, exception, f#, c#-to-f#

I'm trying to convert this piece of C# to F#:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
try {
    webClient.DownloadString (url);
} catch (WebException e) {
    var response = e.Response as HttpWebResponse;
    if (response == null)
        throw;
    using (response) {
        using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream ()) {
            string text = new StreamReader (data).ReadToEnd ();
            throw new Exception (response.StatusCode + ": " + text);
        }
    }
}
```

I've come up with this for now, but it doesn't compile because I cannot use `let` or `use` inside a **with** block apparently:

```ml
let Download(url: string) =
    use webClient = new WebClient ()
    try
        webClient.DownloadString(url)
    with
        | :? WebException as ex when ex.Response :? HttpWebResponse ->
             use response = ex.Response :?> HttpWebResponse
             use data = response.GetResponseStream()
             let text = new StreamReader (data).ReadToEnd ()
             failwith response.StatusCode + ": " + text
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little bit of splitting things up and using parentheses would help you a lot here:

```ml
let download (url : string) = 
    use webClient = new WebClient()
    try
        webClient.DownloadString(url)
    with
        | :? WebException as ex when (ex.Response :? HttpWebResponse) ->
             use response = ex.Response :?> HttpWebResponse
             use data = response.GetResponseStream()
             use reader = new StreamReader(data)
             let text = reader.ReadToEnd()
             failwith (response.StatusCode.ToString() + ": " + text)
```

This function compiles and works as expected.

I'm not an expert, but if I had to guess I'd say that the expression after `when` has to be in brackets to enforce the correct order of evaluation (so type check first, then `when` it), not strictly left-to-right.

Same thing goes for `failwith`, for the string concatenation to be evaluated first it should be in brackets.

Comment: +1 last line can alternately be `failwith <| response.StatusCode.ToString() + ": " + text`

Comment: The reverse pipe <| is frowned upon in typical use, its preferable to use the parentheses. Unless theres is a good reason for using the reverse pipe.

Comment: @7sharp9: I haven't seen any frowns. This is exactly how the reverse pipe is intended to be used.

Comment: 'failwithf "%O: %s" response.StatusCode text'

Comment: @Daniel Just passing on advice Don Syme gave me recently in a code review, I have a penchant of using them a bit just to avoid parentheses, which more often than not makes the code more difficult to read.